# XML Created in TSQL Used as ADODB.Recordset

Tags: sql-server, xml, vb.net, t-sql, adodb

I am attempting to use XML that was generated from a stored procesure in our MS SQL database as a Recordset in a VS2005 Application. The issue I am having is that when reading in the xml as a string, the string result comes in as "System.Byte[]". Seeing this I changed the datatype from String to Byte() and tried to use the Byte array. The Byte array does not seem to have anything to do with the data I want to be receiving. I am wondering if there is a way to handle SQL generated XML files that I am not aware of. Here is some sample code.

This is what the result of the stored procedure looks like when in SQL SMS

[image]

With this code I get the System.byte[] as my string:

```
Dim ADOrs As ADODB.Recordset
Dim SQLString1 As New System.Text.StringBuilder(180)
Dim catzzz as String

SQLString1.Append("exec reports_selectReportMetaData @companyCode = '001'")

ADOrs = fnReturnRecordset(SQLString1.ToString) 'function executes the query

Do While Not ADOrs.EOF
    catzzz = ADOrs("XML_F52E2B61-18A1-11d1-B105-00805F49916B").Value.ToString
    Debug.WriteLine(catzzz)
Loop
```

This is the way I get the really odd Byte Array

```
Dim ADOrs As ADODB.Recordset
Dim SQLString1 As New System.Text.StringBuilder(180)
Dim catzzz As Byte()

SQLString1.Append("exec reports_selectReportMetaData @companyCode = '001'")

ADOrs = fnReturnRecordset(SQLString1.ToString)'function executes the query

Do While Not ADOrs.EOF
    catzzz = ADOrs("XML_F52E2B61-18A1-11d1-B105-00805F49916B").Value           
Loop
```

The Byte array looks like
[image]

And when converted to ASCII using

```
catX = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(catzzz)
```

the first three characters (that should be `<rt` ) Come up as

[image]

So I think my main issue is that I am missing the proper way to bring in the XML created in SQL

Any Ideas would be appricated!

Comment: Any reason you use the old ADODB objects instead of the ADO.NET classes?

Comment: No good reason. I am adding a few new things to an old application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up changing from a stored procedure to a function so that we would be returend a value instead of just having the command executed. This solved the `System.Byte[]` issue.